# Reseting form value upon submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I need help with clearing out a form input when the form has been submitted. When I submit the form, the information that I put in stays there, is there a way I can clear this out? Thanks so much for taking time out of your day to help me. Here is the code

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  function getData(e) {
    setData(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  //function that grabs user input and insert into function
  const inputValue = () => {
    var userSet = data.split("");
    getRandom(userSet);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>LIA</h1>
      <Chalkboard />

      <h1>Letter set: {data}</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input onChange={getData} className="inputField" type="text" placeholder="Enter letters" />
        <button onClick={inputValue} value="Start">
          Start
        </button>
      </form>
  
    </div>
  );
};

export default IntervalFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have a `value` property on your input field. This property in this case should contain the `data` variable. So, this way, on the `handleSubmit` method, you can call `setData(null)` or `setData("")` so as to reset the content of the input field.

Comment: Thank you Lukas! This works, but I have a question, so I want <h1>{data}</h1> to keep rending on the page (so users can see what they typed in) but when I add value={data} and then setData("") to the handle submit function, the <h1>{data}</h1> also resets? Will I have to use a different set of state to stop this from happening?

Comment: I guess you want what user typed before to stay. Yes, the solution could be to have another state containing the previous data.